# How to create tar archive in a different directory?

Tags: tar

I want to create a tar archive in a different directory rather than the current directory.

I tried this command:

```
tar czf file.tar.gz file1 -C /var/www/
```

but it creates the archive in the current directory. Why?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of `-C` (which is not strange as its documented vaguely). For details see http://serverfault.com/q/416002/86283.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that globing (eg. `*`) does not work as indented when one uses the `-C` flag. Because the globing will take place before `tar` change the directory. But for your purpose you don't need this flag as shown by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The easy way, if you don't particularly *need* to use `-C` to tell `tar` to change to some other directory, is to simply specify the full path to the archive on the command line. Then you can be in whatever directory you prefer to create the directory structure that you want inside the archive.

The following will create the archive `/var/www/file.tar.gz` and put `file1` from the current directory (whatever that happens to be) in it, with no in-archive path information.

```
tar czf /var/www/file.tar.gz file1
```

The path (to either the archive, the constituent files, or both) can of course also be relative. If `file1` is in `/tmp`, you are in `/var/spool` and want to create the archive in `/var/www`, you could use something like:

```
tar czf ../www/file1.tar.gz /tmp/file1
```

There's a million variations on the theme, but this should get you started. Add the `v` flag if you want to see what `tar` actually does.

Comment: You could also use a relative path.

Comment: @N.N. Absolutely, but since we have no idea what `$PWD` is, it seemed safest to use an absolute path in the example.

Comment: Indeed, I just though that it made sense to include that to show that it is an available option for solving the problem.

Comment: That way, the path of `file1` in the tar archive will be `/tmp`. This may or may not be what you expect.

Comment: What about the hard way? :)

Answer (score 13):

I think, it should be:
`tar czf file.tar.gz -C /var/www/ file1`

Which works for me. It tells to change directory and then choose file.

Comment: Creates `file.tar.gz` in the current directory. `-C` affects only what follows it. And supposedly doesn't affect `-f`. `tar (GNU tar) 1.34`

Comment: This creates the `tar.gz` in the current directory and adding `file1` from `/var/www` without `/var/www` as prefix. It's worth mentioning that this is the opposite the OP wants, but is also quite useful. Also mind that glob `*` does not work here!!

Answer (score 10):

I turn the compressed data into a stream (`-`) and easily rename and locate (`>`) wherever I choose (I also always `tar` the relative path (`./`) so it's easier to deal with  when uncompressing)

```shell
tar -cvf - ./dir-to-compress/* > /location-of-new-file/filename.tar
```

Comment: That doesn't help with individual files, and `-C` is much more idiomatic (and shorter).

Answer (score -3):

Worked perfectly

```
cd /home; tar -czvf - /var/log/* > varlog.tar.gz
```